# Como pegar o nome da rede Wi-Fi (SSID)?

Tags: java, android

Estou querendo fazer um app que pegue as informações da conexão Wi-Fi, que o celular esta conectado, sendo mais especifico eu quero fazer um app que pegue o nome (SSID) da rede Wi-Fi em que o celular esta conectado. É possível fazer isso?
Se for, poderiam mostrar como ou me mandar links que mostrem como.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim, tem jeito. Você precisa de uma classe chamada [WifiInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo)

Adicione essas permissões no arquivo de `manifest`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

E o código especificamente, sem uso de um broadcast:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo;
String ssid = null;

wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
if (wifiInfo.getSupplicantState() == SupplicantState.COMPLETED) {
    ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();
}
```

- A partir do Android 8.1 (API 27), você também precisa adicionar esta permissão ao `manifest`, caso esteja trabalhando com essa API:

`ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` ou `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21391395/get-ssid-when-wifi-is-connected

Answer (score 1):

Use um objecto [WifiManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager) obtido com `Context.getSystemService()`.

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```

Use o método `getScanResults()` para obter a lista dos *access point* detectados.

```
List<ScanResult> scanResults = wifi.getScanResults();
```

Cada elemento da lista contem [informações detalhadas](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult) de cada um dos *access point* detectados.

O SSID pode ser obtido com

```
String ssid = scanResults[i].SSID; // i = 0 para o primeiro access point
```

São necessárias as permissões ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION ou ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION.